# Upgrade Pubs and Northwind Databases Failed in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS Ultimate 2013 and SQL Server 2014 Standard. I try to upgrade Pubs and Northwind databases but the operation fails with the following snapshot:

[image]

Besides that, I followed paths introduced in some corners of the net but I got no interesting results. What should I do?

Thanks

Update[Problem solved by @marc_s]:

The SQL Server 2012 Northwind database version bypassed the obstacles I had. Here's the link: http://businessimpactinc.com/install-northwind-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says

> User instance flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server

You seem to be trying to use

```
 User Instance=true
```

in your connection string, but that is supported **exclusively** in SQL Server **Express** - no other edition (and therefore, it's **not supported** on SQL Server Standard).

You will need to **attach** the `.mdf` files (or run the creational SQL scripts for those two databases) **on your server** instance¨and then connect to those database **on the server**

Comment: I attached the .mdf files and the User Instance was already set to false but the error is still. I also used SQLCmd.exe tool and run the scripts but when I want to for example display the Tables I got "An incompatible SQL Server version was detected."

Comment: @atoi.powered: from which SQL Server version are those `.mdf` files?? SQL Server 2014 doesn't support SQL Server 2000 or 2005 files anymore....

Comment: Well, those are SQL Server 2000 files which I downloaded from the MS website. I'm trying to find a way to upgrade them to make them usable in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @atoi.powered: [here is the Northwind DB for SQL Server 2012](http://businessimpactinc.com/install-northwind-database/) which works in SQL Server 2014 as well (tested it myself)